# Как реализовать подсказки только с городами при вводе названия города в инпут используя API Яндекс.Карт?

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

В своем проекте мы используем API Яндекс.Карт для получения списка подсказок с городами, в названии которых фигурируют введенные в инпут символы. Но вместо того, чтобы получать только города, мы получаем еще и всякие велодорожки, парки, железные дороги и т.д.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как избавиться от всякого "мусора" и получать только города?
Как пример идеальной реализации см. изображение[image: Пример из Яндекс.Лавки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для подсказок Яндекс выделил саджест в отдельный сервис — **Геосаджест**. И его [документация предлагает](https://yandex.ru/dev/geosuggest/doc/ru/request) для вашей задачи использовать параметр **types=locality**.